# C printf cross-platform format without warnings

Tags: c++, c, format, printf, cross-platform

How do you write code to compile cross-platform without warnings.  For example, I don't get warnings on x64 platform, but I do on ARM (raspberry PI):

warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘size_t {aka unsigned int}

Needless to say I don't want to disable warnings.

More examples and scenarios:

```
warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, 
but argument 5 has type ‘uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}’  

uint64_t Created;       // 8 bytes
time_t now = time(NULL);
"Current time: %li sec, %lu nanosecs", now, msg.Created
```

size_t is probably the highest offender:

Basic use of sizeof:

```
warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, 
but argument 4 has type ‘unsigned int’
tr_debug("pbJobs size: %lu", sizeof(pbJobs));
```

tr_debug is equivalent of printf for Mbed OS platform.  Yes, I compile on Mbed OS and Linux.

Comment: By using proper format specifiers for the types used? It is specifically easy with standard types which you are using.

Comment: Read the docs to find the correct format specifier for each standard type.

Comment: Post the code that causes the waring and the types of its parameters.

Comment: Don't use `*printf()` with C++ and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: Can you use `std::cout` and avoid the issue?

Comment: There is a lot of assumptions that people made here.  1st of all not everybody has access to all of C++.  2nd the reason for the question is that on cross-platform systems size_t structure is taken as an argument and thus I work with size_t data type.  3rd is I work with existing libraries that might be using sprintf.  I just imported C code into CPP project.  So, I really need a stanard sprintf support.  On one system it is of one size and on another system it is of another type.  There is no one specifier that fits them all.  Some comments show lack of knowledge.

Comment: Daemons log, log messages use format strings.  If printf or its other forms where not used in production it would not be in use.

Comment: "not everybody has access to all of C++." + "I really need a stanard sprintf support." --> It would have been clearer to tag this question C and not C++.  Dual tagging confuses if a C _or_ C++ solution is needed or if a C _and_ C++ solution is needed.

Comment: `printf()` with `time_t` is **not** as simply as casting to a wide integer nor using a matching printf specifier (there is none).  `time_t` is not even necessarily an integer.  A good answer is too small for this comment space.  IAC, I suspect a dupe exist on printing `time_t`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `size_t`, assuming you have a sufficiently modern C library, use `%zu`.

If you can't use the `z` modifier (some older libraries unfortunately don't support it), cast to a wide-enough known type when printing, and then use a width specifier appropriate to that type:

```
size_t sz = sizeof(whatever);
...
printf("%lu", (unsigned long)sz);
```

This works *as long as* you're never working with a size larger than 4 billion or so, i.e. that can fit in 32 bits.  If you're on a system where `size_t` is 64 bits but `long` is 32, you've theoretically got the problem of a size which `size_t` can hold but `%lu` can't print.  Whether this is a problem for you, and what to do if it is, is up to you.  (The ideal solution, if your library supports it, is to go back to `%zu`, which is the preferred solution and doesn't have this problem in 32-bit, 64-bit, or any other sized environments.  Or I guess you could use `unsigned long long` and `%llu`.)

Comment: On Windows this cast is narrowing.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Right.  Discussion added.

Answer (score 0):

This particular warning can be avoided by using explicitly sized integers instead of the native data types.

```
#include <cstdint>

int8_t a = 15; //usually an alias for char
uint16_t b = 4980; //usually an alias for unsigned short
uint32_t c = 1234567890; //usually an alias for unsigned int or unsigned long
int64_t d = 908070605040302010ll; //usually an alias for long long
```

The trick with the sized integers is that if, for example, `long` were 32-bits on one platform, but 64 bits on another, any uses of `long` would be non-portable. But `int64_t` will **always** be 64-bits, or else it simply won't exist on the given platform.

In your case specifically, your code seems to be presuming that `size_t` will always be 64-bits, but there's no guarantee of that. So you should be using `uint64_t` instead, which guarantees that whatever underlying data type it ends up using, it will be 64 bits (and unsigned, which is the only guarantee associated with `size_t`).

Comment: Nope, one might say that `uint32_t` is `%u` (e.g. `x86_64`) while another architecture might say `uint32_t` is `%lu` (e.g. `armv7-m`)